# How to memorize tons of names?

Tags: personal-care

How many of you have actually pretended to remember someone and acted like you’re never forgetting names?

“Hey, man. How are you?”

“What’s up dude! Long time.”

You avoid any type of conversation that would include his or her name, and just wait for the name to just end up being mentioned by someone else. Or wait to see if you can somehow spot the name on the person’s notebook. Or see if you steal their wallet and then check their I.D.

So if you could remember the name from the beginning all this awkward situation could be avoided.

Now folks any advice on remembering names(a lot of names)?

Comment: This needs a mind hack, which is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remembering names/nouns by the quantity isn't effective, you're mind needs to attach those to the person and once you recognise someone, their name will be floating around somewhere (if you have already been told what it is) be it either side of the iceberg. Therefore the only solution would be a 'mind hack'. You could however post the first part of your question on the [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) exchange to perhaps come up with a solution to alternatives of avoiding the mentioning of their name to avoid embarrassment. What I tend to do is be straight with the person and admit I do not remember their name, most people aren't actually offended by this.
Note: I would have posted this as a comment if it wern't for the limitations to the number of characters.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I am going to move this question to the English Language & usage

Comment: No problem, good luck! :-)

Comment: just post a continued comment...

Comment: Ah, good point!